# how to print specific value from api response using python

Tags: python, string, api

How to extract specific value from API response?i want to capture "namedEntityRecognition" from the below response where "eadcd259-525a-59b1-b0be-fcecc94f2f18/e8aea4b0-7c83-5799-b515-4172f9c5e1dc" is always dynamic.

{'ACQUIRED_OBJECT', 'serviceOutput': {'namedEntityRecognition': ['eadcd259-525a-59b1-b0be-fcecc94f2f18/e8aea4b0-7c83-5799-b515-4172f9c5e1dc'}

Comment: Use `json.loads()` to make it a `dict` and just index it like a normal dictionary

Comment: `import json; api_string = someApi.get(url); json_to_dict = json.loads(api_string); print(json_to_dict["namedEntityRecognition"])`